# How to check the dependencies of dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my code I've added the `espresso-core`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dependencies"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I usually find its dependencies reading the `pom.xml` file but this is not the case as you can see in the picture below.
[image]

## Question

How can I check the dependencies of `espresso-core` if there is not a pom file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just look up the dependencies:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.espresso/espresso-core/3.2.0

UPDATE:
Not sure why that version doesn't have any dependencies list.  If you look other versions show them for example:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.espresso/espresso-core/3.1.1